# How to move WordPress from one host's root to other's sub-directory using duplicator?

Tags: wordpress

I host a wordpress blog (xyz.com) on root directory of host A.

Now I move to host B and domain (xyz.com) remains the same.

I use duplicator and try to install blog on sub-directory (xyz) of new host's root.

When I run xyz.com/installer.php, I get this error:

Internal Server Error

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

How do i fix it?

Comment: Have you imported database too?

Comment: @ArshadHussain...he doesn't need to. He's using [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)

Comment: Where have you uploaded the files on the new server? If it's in a subdirectory, you need to navigate to `xyz.com/subdirectory/installer.php`. Also, are you sure your nameservers have been changed to point to the new server?

Comment: @mevius ... nameservers are already pointing to the host B ... and xyz.com already points to xyz.com/subdicrectory/